# Append text in UWP(XAML)?

Tags: c#, xaml, append, win-universal-app

There is a command **appendText** in *Windows Form Application* to add text in a text box without removing previous texts.

But I didn't find any command in **UWP**(XAML) applications like **appendText**. What should I use in **UWP**(XAML) to do the same like **appendText**?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid it's not possible. But if you wish increase speed you can bind TextBox value with compiled binding **x:Bind**
In this case if you change value in c# code-behind it will be changed very fast in UI

Text rendering is optimized in Windows 10. It's already 50% faster then in Windows 8.1
If you want to optimize TextBlock loading speed then you can:

1. Set IsTextSelectionEnabled property to false and CharacterSpacing to 0 if you want have good TextBlock performance. LineHeight should be also set 0.
2. Use default typography
3. TextTrimming: Only the None, CharacterEllipsis, and WordEllipsis values
4. Set up text with Text="" property

   ```
   <StackPanel>
   <TextBlock Text="This text is on the fast path."/>
   <TextBlock>This text is NOT on the fast path.</TextBlock>
   <StackPanel/>
   ```

You can read this and another recommendations here: [Text block Performance considerations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/text-block)

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to do this:

```
{
    //prevString = the string availabe in textbox before adding newString
    //newString = the string I want to add as appendText

    //Get all string in textbox in prevText string
    string prevString = reciveTextBox.Text;
    //always print the prevString before printing newString
    reciveTextBox.Text = prevString + newString;
}
```

It works exactly as **appendText**!

Comment: Sure it works)) But it's not immutable (hope that you know that StringBuilder is faster way to concatenate strings then just string1+string2)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way:

```
textBox1.Text += "new text";
```

Same as **appendText**